# How to set the property expected status code range on a TrafficManager via the az cli

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-traffic-manager

I am not able to set expected code ranges for a Traffic Manager Profile via the az cli.

I get the error:

```
Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [MonitorConfigExpectedStatusCodeRangesItem] an object of type , DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [MonitorConfigExpectedStatusCodeRangesItem] an object of type 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 573, in body
    data = deserializer._deserialize(data_type, data)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1260, in _deserialize
    self._deserialize(local_type, value)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1260, in _deserialize
    self._deserialize(local_type, value)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1269, in _deserialize
    return self.deserialize_data(data, response)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1445, in deserialize_data
    return self.deserialize_type[iter_type](data, data_type[1:-1])
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1474, in deserialize_iter
    type(attr)
msrest.exceptions.DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [MonitorConfigExpectedStatusCodeRangesItem] an object of type 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 197, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 373, in execute
    six.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    result = cmd(params)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 182, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/arm.py", line 512, in handler
    result = setter(**setterargs)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/mgmt/trafficmanager/operations/profiles_operations.py", line 347, in create_or_update
    body_content = self._serialize.body(parameters, 'Profile')
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 576, in body
    SerializationError, "Unable to build a model: "+str(err), err)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py", line 54, in raise_with_traceback
    raise error.with_traceback(exc_traceback)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 573, in body
    data = deserializer._deserialize(data_type, data)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1260, in _deserialize
    self._deserialize(local_type, value)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1260, in _deserialize
    self._deserialize(local_type, value)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1269, in _deserialize
    return self.deserialize_data(data, response)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1445, in deserialize_data
    return self.deserialize_type[iter_type](data, data_type[1:-1])
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py", line 1474, in deserialize_iter
    type(attr)
msrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model: Cannot deserialize as [MonitorConfigExpectedStatusCodeRangesItem] an object of type , DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [MonitorConfigExpectedStatusCodeRangesItem] an object of type
```

I have set up a TrafficManager profile in Azure and now I want to update that profile with the expected status code ranges. This is not able to be set during creation.

The command I use is:

```
az network traffic-manager profile update --resource-group RG20BRAM-DEV --name test --set monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges='200'
```

Anyone who can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

With kind regards,
Bram

Comment: I am guessing it might not be possible yet: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the Azure Traffic Manager profile with the CLI command like this:

```
az network traffic-manager profile update -g groupName -n trafficName --set monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges[0].max=301
```

and

```
az network traffic-manager profile update -g groupName -n trafficName --set monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges[0].min=301
```

Take a look at the properties of [Traffic Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2018-04-01/trafficmanagerprofiles) and then choose which one you want to update with the right way. Hope this will help you.

**Update**

The screenshot of the Update:

[image]

When you create the profile without setting the property monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges. You can first set it with the CLI command:

```
az network traffic-manager profile update -g charles -n charlesTrafficManager --set monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges='[{"min":200,"max":299}]'
```

The screenshot of the command execute:

[image]

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your answer. When I do this I get an "error": 
    index 0 doesn't exist on [0]

Comment: Do I need to do something first with --add?

Comment: Oh, really? You can show the profile with the command `az network traffic-manager profile` to see how does the profile set. The monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges property is an array.

Comment: When I first created the profile it shows the property as:
`"expectedStatusCodeRanges": null,`. 

But when I do an `--add monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges` it shows the property as `"expectedStatusCodeRanges": []`.
If I then do `--set monitorConfig.expectedStatusCodeRanges[0].min=200` it gives the error `index 0 doesn't exist on expectedStatusCodeRanges`